# What is the difference between the jordan normal forms of the two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Do these matrices have the same Jordan form?

My confusion arises because a jordan block has the form

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_i & 1 \\ 0 &  \ddots  & 1\\ 0& 0& \lambda_i \end{bmatrix}$$

But I don't know what exactly dictates the size of our $J$ i.e. how many elements there are on the diagonals.

Is there a fundamental difference between $A$ and $B$ reflected in their jordan blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a classical Jordan form of $2\times2$, and the second diagonal, both with $0$ as the eigenvalue. For $A$ eigenvalue multiplicity is $2$. For $B$ multiplicity $1$.

Consider also, both the characteristic and minimal polynomials of them:
$$\chi_A(x)=\mu_A(x)=x^2$$
and
$$\chi_B(x)=x^2\quad,\quad \mu_B(x)=x$$

Comment: at https://www.facebook.com/AlgebraMultilineal/photos/a.346826782078389.82074.341191865975214/917024708391924/?type=3&theater check the six general cases for $3\times 3$ matrices

Comment: Just to clarify. When you refer to multiplicity you are referring to the algebraic multiplicity or the geometric multiplicity? And what does the jordan block of $B$ officially look like? Just 0?

Comment: $B$ is just a diagonal matrix.  To understand what behind the idea, please check to the $3\times 3$ case in the link I did provide

Comment: The minimal polynomial of B is x, not 0.

Comment: of course, bien sûr

Answer (score 1):

The ones and zeros in the super-diagonal decide the blocks. The 1 in the $A_{1,2}$ decides that 1 and 2 are in the same block and therefore A has a $2 \times 2$ block. The zero in $B_{1,2}$ decide we have a "block breaker" between 1 and 2.

More complicated example to try and clarify:

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Counting the ones we have "connections" between (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (5,6),(6,7). Calculating $\sum_k A^k$ will then "propagate" these connections in one direction. If you do this by hand you will see that the 0 actually is kind of a "block breaker":

$$\sum_{k=1}^7 A^k = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$

We can also "propagate" in the other direction:

$$\sum_{k=1}^7 (A^T)^k = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&0
\end{array}\right]
$$

These summed together with the identity matrix become:

$$I + \sum_{k=1}^7 (A^T)^k + A^k = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1
\end{array}\right]$$

And now the block structure is really visible.

Comment: your last propagated matrix hasn't the same Jordan decomposition of the $7\times 7$ matrix  $A$ you gave

Comment: check http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Comment: janmarqz: yes I know, Jordan blocks are always upper triangular, the propagation on the transpose was just a way to build rectangular blocks of 1s so the blocks would be easier to see.

Comment: but the propagated matrix you get *changes the information* (conjugacy class) of the original matrix... i wonder what applications (outside math), this technique  of you, has

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the difference between the minimal polynomial vs the characteristic polynomial. They determinant of xI-A and xI-B are both x^2, but look at their minimal polynomials. That governs how the Jordan blocks break up.